# How to rearrange the columns into rows and rows into columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, csv

I want to transform columns into rows and rows into columns. I wrote a python code, but every row is getting repeated. It is not getting properly transformed. Any help would be appreciated.

I am providing a sample .csv file. For further reference.

```
v1 = df.astype(str).agg('/'.join)
v1.index = [df.columns.str.cat(sep=',')] * len(v1)
v1.rename_axis('Events').to_frame('Value').reset_index()
```

This the output I got after the code. I want the files to return non-redundant value in every row:

[image]

I would like the `Events` column to contain single values instead of lists of values and `Value` column should get populated with consecutive data from the transformed column headers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJdLd.png)

Comment: Your example is not very clear, please post the dataframe as a text instead of an image. Maybe `df.T` is what you want.

Comment: Hi@itaishz. I am providing sample data, which kind of matches with my original one. After transformation. It looks unexpected.